# Jquery trying to hide a form

Tags: jquery

On page load, i have two div blocks "replyComment" and "tobereplaced"

```
<div id="replyComment">        
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" action="reply.php" >
    <textarea name="suggestions" rows="5" cols="60" style="resize:none" onfocus="this.value=''">Enter your reply here</textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="hidden2" >  
    <a href="blog.php?page=hm"><img src="html_images/cancel.png" onmouseover="src='html_images/cancelhover.png'" onmouseout="src='html_images/cancel.png'" alt="Cancel"/></a>
    <input type="image" name="Post"  value="Reply" alt="Reply" src="html_images/reply.png" onmouseover="src='html_images/replyhover.png'" onmouseout="src='html_images/reply.png'"/>
</form>
    </div>
      <div name="tobereplaced">
            <img src="html_images/reply.png"  class="ajax-func" onmouseover="src='html_images/replyhover.png'" onmouseout="src='html_images/reply.png'" />
      </div>
```

and i am trying to hide the replyComment div on load and toggle it to show on click of tobereplaced with the following jquery.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".replyComment").hide();
       $(".ajax-func").click(function(evt) {
            $(this).prevAll(".replyComment:first").slideToggle("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass("active");
            return false;
                                            });
       });
```

but the replyComment is not hidden on page load nor does it toggle..i am new to jquery, any help will be appreciated..

Comment: You used ".replyComment" The . (dot) is used for classes, but you have replyComment as an ID so you have to use "#". (#replyComment). Also, that selector is too complicated, you could simply use $("#replyComment").slideToggle().

Answer (score 3):

You use the dot selector if you're referring to an element by its class and the hash selector to refer to an element by ID.
So in your case, you should have:

```
$('#replyComment').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your div is an `id`, but your selector is looking for classes.  Try this:

```
 $("#replyComment").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. ".replyComment" matches a tag with the class replyComment.

For the id you sould the selector "#replyComment".

Try studing a little bit more selectors, they are the soul of jQuery and browse http://jqapi.com/ for references.